# Change Page Title in DNN Programatically from Razor

Tags: asp.net, razor, dotnetnuke

I've searched a lot for "How to change the title programatically" and only got this result which doesn't work, at least in Razor scripts

```
DotNetNuke.Framework.CDefault tp = (DotNetNuke.Framework.CDefault)this.Page;
tp.Title = "New Title Here";
```

This doesn't work in razor host scripts, is there any other solutions to change the page title from Razor host script ?

Comment: Do you have access to your template/layout file (assuming there is one)? You could put a `@ViewBag.Title` in the title portion of the html so you could set in all the pages

Comment: The template is a DNN Skin which is an ascx file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After many trials and merging others codes, I've found the solution

Using this will give you access to the page access, so you can do whatever you want with it, changing title etc.

```
var pageObj = Context.CurrentHandler as Page;
pageObj.Title = "My New Title for the page";
```

And this code will give access to the DNN Page, So you can insert controls etc.

```
DotNetNuke.Framework.CDefault tp = (DotNetNuke.Framework.CDefault)Context.CurrentHandler;
tp.FindControl("Head").Controls.Add(NewControlObj);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing Pola.  Works great in C# Razor on DNN.

Comment: @MDM Glad that it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd just like to add to Pola's answer with something that will hopefully work "out of the box".

It's hard to find examples that work directly with DNN, so I submit the following;

```
@{
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlMeta objMetaDescription = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlMeta();
objMetaDescription.Name = "DESCRIPTION";
objMetaDescription.Content = "This will be the meta description content";

DotNetNuke.Framework.CDefault tp = (DotNetNuke.Framework.CDefault)Context.CurrentHandler;
tp.FindControl("Head").Controls.Add(objMetaDescription);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way working for me:

```
((DotNetNuke.Framework.CDefault)this.Page).Title = "your title";
```