# Change Title and Add Facebook OG Meta in Razor

Tags: c#, facebook, razor, 2sxc

Blog posts for the 2sxc Blog App are not shared with proper titles by Facebook share buttons. Currently blog post Razor handles title-change with javascript. Facebook and search engines don't like that. As a result they end up getting the default title from the parent page. To fix I need to change page title via the C# Razor file "_Post Details.cshtml".  Also adding og:title and og:image meta would be a bonus.

I can build meta easy enough:

```
// build facebook meta
HtmlMeta metaOGTitle = new HtmlMeta();
metaOGTitle.Attributes.Add("property", "og:title");    
metaOGTitle.Content = post.Title;
HtmlMeta metaOGImage = new HtmlMeta();
metaOGImage.Attributes.Add("property", "og:image");    
metaOGImage.Content = post.Image.ToLower();
```

The trick is getting a reference to the page header.  I have looked at several old posts.  I get a "cannot convert type 'System.Dynamic.DynamicObject' to 'DotNetNuke.Framework.CDefault" when trying this code from Chris Hammond:

```
DotNetNuke.Framework.CDefault tp = (DotNetNuke.Framework.CDefault)this.Page;
tp.Title = "This is my page title";
```

Using Page.Header or Page.FindControl("Head") leads to null reference exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK Thanks to Birsky89 at https://gist.github.com/birksy89/c755fd83d0943b5ab94b and Pola Edward at [Change Page Title in DNN Programatically from Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22761428/change-page-title-in-dnn-programatically-from-razor) I have been able to put together a reasonably succinct solution.

I added the code to the top of my "Post Details.cshtml" and it's working like a charm.

```
@using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

    // build facebook meta
    HtmlMeta metaOGTitle = new HtmlMeta();
    metaOGTitle.Attributes.Add("property", "og:title");    
    metaOGTitle.Content = post.Title;
    HtmlMeta metaOGImage = new HtmlMeta();
    metaOGImage.Attributes.Add("property", "og:image");    
    metaOGImage.Content = post.Image.ToLower();

    // change the title and add facebook meta      
    var pageObj = Context.CurrentHandler as Page;
    pageObj.Title = post.Title;
    pageObj.FindControl("Head").Controls.Add(metaOGTitle);
    pageObj.FindControl("Head").Controls.Add(metaOGImage);
```

Comment: Glad you found an answer. Best mark this questions as answered, so users can benefit.